# Is set algebra or $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following set an algebra, $\sigma$-algebra, or neither? If neither, what is the algebra generated by it?

$$S=\left\{A\subset \mathbb{N} \mid \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|A \cap[1,n]|} n = 1 \right\}$$

I am confused by the limit expression on the right. Could someone please explain that. If I had to try anything here, I would say that if $A =\varnothing$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|A \cap[1,n]|}{n}\neq 1$ so that $S$ is neither an algebra or $\sigma$ algebra, since $\varnothing \notin S$. Would this be correct? Also, what would be the algebra generated by $S$? How can I figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

$A\in S$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, $\frac{|A\cap [1,n]|}{n}>1-\epsilon$.

So for any finite number $m$ of sets $A_i \in S$, and any $\epsilon>0$, you can let $N=\max(N_i)$, with each $N_i$ chosen so the fraction for $A_i$ is greater than $1-\epsilon/m$, so that $\cap A_i$ is in $S$.

But $S$ is clearly not closed under complements, so not an algebra.

Define $T$ such that $B\in T$ if $B$ is the complement of some $A \in S$. Try to see if $T$ is closed under finite intersections.

Now consider $S \cup T$. What is the intersection of a finite number of its sets?

Comment: If $\{B_1,...,B_n\}$ is a finite collection of elements of $T$, then $B_i=A_{i}^c$ for each $i$. Then $\cap B_i=\cap(A_i^c)=(\cup A_i)^c$. So it would be closed? Would $S \cup T$ be the algebra generated by it?

Comment: Yes, if a finite collection of sets in $S\cup T$ contained all sets from $S$, then the intersection would be in $S$, but if the finite collection contained a set in $T$, then the intersection would be in $T$. Also, the complement of any set in $S\cup T$ is clearly in $S\cup T$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A = \emptyset$, then $A \cap [1,n] = \emptyset$ for all $n$, so $|A \cap [1,n]|=0$ for all $n$, so
$$\frac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n}=0$$
for all $n$,
so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n}=0.$$

So, as you guessed, $\emptyset \notin S$ and therefore $S$ is not an algebra.

Comment: Would $|A\cap[1,n]|$ be the cardinality?

Comment: @Tasso Yes. If $X$ is a set $|X|$ usually refers to the cardinality of $X$.